# GORM Hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I have the following Grails domain objects

```
class ProductType {
    String name
    static hasMany = [attributes: Attribute]
}

class Attribute {

    Boolean mandatory = false
    Integer seq

    static belongsTo = [productType: ProductType]
}
```

I would like to get all `ProductType`s and their mandatory `Attribute`s. Furthermore, I'd like the selected `Attribute`s to be eagerly loaded and sorted by the `seq` property. I've tried all kinds of HQL and Criteria queries, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all ProductTypes that have mandatory attributes, with those attributes eagerly loaded:

```
def types = ProductType.executeQuery("""
   select distinct type from ProductType type
   left join fetch type.attributes attribute
   where attribute.mandatory=true""")
```

The attributes are in mapped Sets, so there's no ordering, but it's easy enough to collect and sort them:

```
def sortedAttributes = types.collect { it.attributes }.flatten().sort { it.seq }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can get a sorted list of the many side by implementing a Comparable Interface in the many-side domain, and injecting SortedSet in the one-side (instead of the default Set).

```
class ProductType {
    String name
    SortedSet attributes
    static hasMany = [attributes: Attribute]
}

class Attribute implements Comparable {

    Boolean mandatory = false
    Integer seq

    static belongsTo = [productType: ProductType]

    int compareTo(obj) {
       seq.compareTo(obj.seq)
    }
}
```